# How can I redirect to a page depend on different user group correctly by django?

Tags: python, html, django, web

I am creating a feature to let the banned user (user without any group) go to a specific page `banned_alert` when they click the "post", because they are not allowed to do so. But then when I test this feature, the Chrome shows `This page isn’t working | the IP redirected you too many times.` Can somebody tell me how to do it correctly? Did I miss any configuration? Below is my code snippets. Thank you for your time!

base.html: (`has_group` function already works correctly somewhere else)

```html
{% load get_group %}
{% if request.user|has_group:"mod" or request.user|has_group:"default" or user.is_staff %}
<a class="nav-link" href="/create-post">Post</a>
{% else %}
<a class="nav-link" href="/banned_alert">Post</a>
{% endif %}
```

banned_alert.html:

```html
{% extends 'main/base.html' %}
{% block title %}Your account has been banned by Admin{% endblock %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
<h2>Please contact the Admin!</h2>
{% endblock %}
```

view.py

```py
def banned_alert(request):
    return redirect('/banned_alert')
```

urls.py

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('home', views.home, name='home'),
    path('sign-up', views.sign_up, name='sign_up'),
    path('create-post', views.create_post, name='create_post'),
    path('banned_alert', views.banned_alert, name='banned_alert'),
]
```

Comment: The `banned_alert` view redirects to `banned_alert`, creating an infinite redirection loop. It should just be a normal view. As an aside, your logic should be server-side, not client-side - which it essentially is being in the template.

Answer (score 0):

You have a recursion:

this is your path

`path('banned_alert', views.banned_alert, name='banned_alert'),`

1. User visit this `banned_alert` path,
2. it redirects user to view `banned_alert`
3. Which redirects user back to url `banned_alert`
4. and it redirects back to view `banned_alert`
5. reapeat N times (it has no ending)

best way to ban user is to create a flag in his model:

`models.py`

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_banned = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

if you want to ban `user`, change `user's` field `is_banned` to `true`, and then in your template or view, check if user is banned or not, and do your logic according to it

> By the way, in your `ulrs.py` you need to close paths with backslash like this `path('home/', views.home, name='home'),`